# emoji from output is different on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, regex, unicode, subprocess, cross-platform

On Windows:

```py
import re
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'black'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stderr = output.stderr.decode()
assert re.match(r'No Path provided. Nothing to do \\U0001f634\r\n', stderr)
```

On Linux, however, I need to change the regular expression in two places:

```py
import re
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'black'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stderr = output.stderr.decode()
assert re.match(r'No Path provided. Nothing to do \U0001f634\n', stderr)
```

I understand why I need to change `\r\n` to `\n` - it's because of the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

However, why do I need to change `'\\U0001f634'` to `'\U0001f634'`? Is there a way of writing the above assertion in a cross-platform way?

Comment: No idea why, but you might use an alternation here with `\r` set to optional: `r'No Path provided. Nothing to do (?:\\U0001f634|\U0001f634)\r?\n'`

Comment: Thanks, have gone with that for now

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference here is probably because the emoji is shown as its hex vaue in Windows and as a literal emoji char in Linux.

The solution here is to match `\r` as an optional char by adding `?` quantifier after it and use an alternation to match either the escaped emoji or a literal emoji:

```py
r'No Path provided. Nothing to do (?:\\U0001f634|\U0001f634)\r?\n'
```

If the dot is a literal dot, please consider escaping it, otherwise, `.` matches any char but a line break char:

```py
r'No Path provided\. Nothing to do (?:\\U0001f634|\U0001f634)\r?\n'
```

**Details**

- `No Path provided. Nothing to do`  - literal `No Path provided. Nothing to do`  text
- `(?:\\U0001f634|\U0001f634)` - either a `\` followed with `U0001f634` or a  emoji
- `\r?` - an optional CR
- `\n` - an LF char.